# Count records in database

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, vb.net, .net-3.5

I have the code below which does work, but I need to add further functionality to it.  The functionality I want to add to it is the text I have commented in the code below.

```
Dim objSQLConnection As SqlConnection
Dim objSQLCommand As SqlCommand

Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim intID As Integer = CType(Request.Form("ID"), Integer)
    Dim strHeading As String = CType(Request.Form("Heading"), String)
    Dim intState As Integer = CType(Request.Form("State"), Integer)
    Dim strUser As String = CType(Request.Form("User"), String)

    objSQLConnection = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("connString"))

    ''#count if records with this user already exist in the database below

    If intState = 1 Then
        objSQLCommand = New SqlCommand("insert into table1 (id, heading, user) values (@intID, @strHeading, @strUser)", objSQLConnection)

        objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@intID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = intID
        objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@strHeading", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = strHeading
        objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@strUser", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = strUser
    ElseIf intState = 0 Then
        objSQLCommand = New SqlCommand("delete from table1 where id = @intID and user = @strUser", objSQLConnection)

        objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@intID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = intID
        objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@strUser", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = strUser
    End If

    objSQLCommand.Connection.Open()
    objSQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    objSQLCommand.Connection.Close()
End
```

Before the if statement, I want to find out if the database already has records with the username in the strUser variable.  What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Please don' t repost the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658869/duplicate-default-records-if-user-has-no-records

Comment: I thought the questions where different, question one, count users, question two, duplicate records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to do all of this for you but a simple way to check the count is store the result of a stored procedure (SQL Server) into a SqlDataReader and check if the count > 0 or if HasRows = True.

```
With (myObjectCommand)
    .Parameters.Add("@strUser", SqlDbType.Varchar, 3).Value = myUser
    myReader = .ExecuteReader
End With

if myReader.HasRows
    return true ?
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough.  Just do ExecuteScalar on the database with a query like "Select field1 from table where username = @username" and pass the strUser into the query object.  Then save the scalar result into a variable (result).  Then you can do if result is <> "", do such and such.